# Does VS has any shortcut like ctrl+q in eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, shortcut, hotkeys

It returns your caret(aka cursor) to the place where you stopped writing code(very useful for fast code browsing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will move to the previously browsed line of code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will move forward). You can download PDF versions of all the default keybindings in Visual Studio 2010 from [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en).

Comment: @Itay Of course :) Take a look at this thread on meta for a good laugh: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper has Ctrl+Shift-Backspace to return to previous editing position. Or Ctrl+Shift+, (Comma) to browse some recent edition places.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what is mentioned in the other answers, you can use the undo/redo trick.  As long as you want to navigate to the last edit position in the current file, a quick undo/redo will take you there.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `View.NavigateBackward`. The actual keystroke depends on your personal settings, but it's probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. If not, go to `Tools/Customize/Commands/Keyboard` to find out what it is for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> That navigate backward and forward.